# You must use the "set" method to update an entry how to rectify in php codengniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

You must use the `set()` method to update an entry.

> Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\task_manager\system\database\DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1273

Comment: add some code in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not updating record correctly

Do like this

**Method 1**

```
$this->db->where('column', $value);
$this->db->set($data); // values should be like this $data = array(id=> 1, 'name' => GNN);
return $this->db->update('table');
```

**Method 2**

```
return $this->db->query( "UPDATE tablename SET name = GNN WHERE id = 1" );
```

For more [read doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Comment: what code you have tried so far? add code in your question.